# Are apps created in Phonegap accepted by the app stores or are they treated differently?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I am very new to mobile application development. I want to create an app for all platforms: iPhone, Android, Windows, Blackberry etc.

As it would take a lot of time to learn all the technologies and create separate applications for each of the technologies, I was searching for a workaround for this.

I found out about Phonegap. And I installed it and created a few simple applications using it. It's very simple and easy to code, as I am a web application developer it's very convenient to code in Phonegap.

My only confusion here is, if I develop an app, and try to deploy it for iPhone, Android Windows etc., would the app be accepted by the Apple app store, Google market place, Windows store? I mean, I have heard that Apple does not accepts all the apps, so, do they accept apps created in Phonegap? Or would would the app created in Phonegap be treated (if at all) differently?

Comment: I removed the "Android" flag as it mainly concerns Iphone and PhoneGap, in my opinion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many apps from many developers on Google Play, the iOS App Store, and the Windows Phone whatever-they-call-it that are built with PhoneGap. You can find many on [the PhoneGap Web site](http://phonegap.com/apps/), complete with links to their market listings.

(FWIW, you should have visited that Web site before asking this question)

There might be specific things your app might do that would cause it to be rejected by one or more of these markets, but just being written in PhoneGap is not one of them.